# How VSCode Handle Conflicting Intellisense extensions on hover

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

1) How VS Code handles a conflict, in our case we want to add some intellisense with hover in the json file. But in some cases, there could be two separate extensions extending the same type of file or conflict with intellisense provided by VS Code itself. In such cases how does the editor decide which intellisense to show? 
2) In Vscode snippets extensions can we give regular expression in prefix to show the auto completion snippet in the specific scope? 
example: In the below given JSON file, I want xyz  to be shown in auto completion only if parent node is abc. Is there a way to define prefix or scope in snippet file for achieving this?
{
    abc :
         {
           xyz : 123
         }
}

Comment: Please separate these two questions into separate posts.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, read the Extension API documentation, particularly the [vscode.languages.RegisterXXX() methods](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_languages).  The rules for handling multiple providers is documented for each provider type.